# How the undo option works on a VBS macro?

Tags: vbscript

Is it possible to explain how to use on a VBscript macro the `DiscardUndo` Property option? An example would be great.

[EmEditor Help - DiscardUndo Property](http://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_window_discard_undo.html)

Because I don't understand why there are two options for VBscript:

```vb
b = DiscardUndo
```

and

```vb
DiscardUndo = b
```

Does it mean that the replace code goes between them? Or what?

Comment: None of this is native VBScript but some third party component using VBScript. Both are valid syntax the first retrieves the flag (known as a getter) the second sets the value of the flag (also known as setters). This is a very basic programming principle it’s how values are returned and set. Recommend reading the [Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/t0aew7h6(v=vs.84)) to understand basic concepts like variable assignment.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about here is [variable assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/t7zd6etz(v=vs.84)) which is a fundamental concept in most programming languages.

In this example the property [`DiscardUndo`](http://www.emeditor.org/en/macro_window_discard_undo.html) holds a flag that determines whether the undo information should be stored or discarded in a bid to improve performance. I’m not familiar with this particular library but as it’s a simple on/off I’d imagine the flag is a boolean value (`True` or `False`).

To assign this property value to a variable you would use;

```vb
Dim IsUndoDiscarded
IsUndoDiscarded = DiscardUndo 'Retrieve the value of DiscardUndo (either True or False)
```

To assign a value to this property you would use;

```vb
DiscardUndo = True 'Discard undo information
```

or;

```vb
DiscardUndo = False 'Keep undo information
```